# Filtrar resultados de uma tabela do Bootgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, front-end, slider, bootgrid

O projeto utiliza o [Bootgrid](http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/documentation) para criar tabelas, e apesar de não ter sido atualizado há um tempo, não posso mudar para outro :/

Assim, preciso implementar um filtro com base no valor de um range slider. O bootgrid já fornece a busca por string, mas não esse filtro. O que preciso é algo parecido com a imagem: ao selecionar 50%, devem aparecer as linhas que possuem um match igual ou maior que 50% (na imagem apareceu só 50% pois foi pela busca).

[image: Como deve funcionar]

A tabela é implementada da seguinte forma:

```
 $(".company-table.with-header").bootgrid({
    columnSelection: false,
    selection: true,
    rowCount: 10,

    css: {
        icon: 'zmdi icon',
        iconColumns: 'zmdi-view-module',
        iconDown: 'zmdi-sort-amount-desc',
        iconRefresh: 'zmdi-refresh',
        iconUp: 'zmdi-sort-amount-asc'
    },
    labels: {
        noResults: "No se encontraron resultados",
        search: "Buscar",
        infos: "Mostrando {{ctx.start}} a {{ctx.end}} de {{ctx.total}} postulaciones"
    },
    caseSensitive: false,
    formatters: {
        "commands-best-match": function (column, row) {
            var actions;

            var id = row.job_id != "" ? row.job_id : row.candidate_id;
            var id2 = row.job_id != "" ? row.candidate_id : "";

            actions = "<a title='Ver Candidato' class='table-action edit-modal' action-url='/Candidato/ModalSeeCandidate' data-row-id='" + id + "' data-row-id2='" + id2 + "'><i class='far fa-eye'></i></a>";
            //actions += "<a href='#' title='Esconder de la lista' class='table-action'><i class='far fa-times-circle'></i></a>";
            actions += "<a href='mailto:" + row.candidate_email + "' title='Contactar' class='table-action'><i class='far fa-envelope'></i></a>";

            return actions;
        },
        "favorite": function (column, row) {
            var color = row.favorite == 1 ? "yellow" : "";
            var cand_id = row.candidate_id;

            return setFavoriteForm(row, cand_id, color);
        },
        "show-postulated": function (column, row) {
            return row.postulated == "True" ? "<i class='fas fa-check-circle checked'></i>" : "";
        }
    }
}).on("loaded.rs.jquery.bootgrid", function (e) {
    tableActions();
});
```

E o slider é implementado como:

```
var slider = document.getElementById("sliderMinMatch");
slider.oninput = function () {
    output.innerHTML = this.value;
}
```

Na [documentação](http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/documentation) fala sobre os métodos, mas não estou conseguindo usar o chaining. Isso funciona:

```
 $(".company-table.with-header").bootgrid("search", "50%");
```

Mas não sei como trocar o 50% pelo valor do slider.

Se alguém puder dar alguma luz ajudaria muito, estou bem perdida com isso.